# activate radio button and calculate textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

I've the below code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isNumberKey(as) {
            var dd = as.value;
            if (isNaN(dd)) {
                dd = dd.substring(0, (dd.length - 1));
                as.value = dd;
            }
        }

        function activate(){
            document.getElementById('rate').readOnly=false;
        }

        function deactivate(){
            document.getElementById('rate').readOnly=true;
            var int = document.calc.loan.value;
            if(int > 50000 && int < 100000){
            document.calc.rate.value=10;
            }
            if(int > 100000 && int < 150000){
            document.calc.rate.value=12;
            }
        }

        function showpay() {
            var a = document.calc.loan.value;
            var b = document.calc.rate.value;
            var c = document.calc.months.value;
            var n = c ;
            var r = b / (12 * 100);
            var p = (a * r * Math.pow((1 + r), n)) / (Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1);
            var prin = Math.round(p * 100) / 100;
            document.calc.pay.value = Math.round(prin);
           // document.calc.totInt.value = round((prin * c) - a);
           // document.calc.totpay.value = round((prin * c) - a);
            document.calc.totInt.value = Math.round((prin * c) - a);
            document.calc.totpay.value = Math.round(prin * c);
        } </script>

</head>

<body class="body">
<header class="mainheader">
<img src="img/logo.gif" alt=""/>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="calculators.html">Calculators</a></li>
<li><a href="contactuS.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header><br>
<div class="maincontent">
<div class="content" style="width:100%">
<article class="topcontent">
<header><h2 style="align:center" title="firstpost"><p align="center" style="color: #CF5C3F;">Loan Calculator</p></h2></header>
<footer>
<p class="post-info"></p>
</footer>
<content>
<p>
<center>
    <form name="calc">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Entry</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Principle($)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="loan" id="loan" placeholder="Enter the amount Required" onkeypress="isNumberKey(this)"/>
      </td><span id="error"/>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Do you know Rate of Interest</td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" onClick="activate()">Yes<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="No" onClick="deactivate()">No
      </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Interest(%)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" placeholder="Enter the Interest Rate" onkeypress="isNumberKey(this)"/>
      </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tenure(in Months)</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="months" id="months" placeholder="Enter the Tenure in Months"  onkeypress="isNumberKey(this)"/>
        </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>EMI</td>
      <td>
        <input name="textfield4" type="text" id="pay" placeholder="Your EMI" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick='showpay()'/></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total Interest Paid</td>
      <td>
        <input name="totInt" type="text" id="totInt" placeholder="Total Interest" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total Repay Amount</td>
      <td>
        <input name="totpay" type="text" id="totpay" placeholder="Total Amount" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</center>

</p>
</content>
</article>
</div>
</div>


<footer class="mainfooter">
<p>this is copyright &copy;</p>
</footer>



</body>
</html>
```

here I'm trying to achieve the below.

1. If user selects, `Yes` radio button, the textbox next to Interest should accept manual input, else, the Interest should be as below.
2. If user enters amount between, 50000 and 100000, the Interest should show 15
3. If user enters amount between, 100000 and 150000, the Interest should show 12
4. else the Interest should show, 18.

and based on this Interest the amount should be calculated.

I'm unable to get that number when I enter the amount and hot No.

please let me know how i can get this.

Thanks

Comment: ultimately you are asking entire solution without try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
<script type="application/javascript">

    function isNumberKey(id) {
            var dd = document.getElementById(id).value;
            if (isNaN(dd)) {
                dd = dd.substring(0, (dd.length - 1));
                document.getElementById(id).value = dd;
            }
        }

        function activate(){
            document.getElementById('rate').readOnly =false;
    console.log(document.getElementById('rate').readOnly)
        }

        function deactivate(){
            document.getElementById('rate').readOnly =true;
        console.log(document.getElementById('rate').readOnly)
            var int = document.calc.loan.value;
            if(int > 50000 && int < 100000){
            document.calc.rate.value=10;
            }
            if(int > 100000 && int < 150000){
            document.calc.rate.value=12;
            }
        }

        function showpay() {
            var a = document.calc.loan.value;

            var b = document.calc.rate.value ? document.calc.rate.value : 1;
            var c = document.calc.months.value;
            var n = c ;
            var r = b / (12 * 100);
            var p = (a * r * Math.pow((1 + r), n)) / (Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1);
            var prin = Math.round(p * 100) / 100;

            document.calc.pay.value = Math.round(prin);
           // document.calc.totInt.value = round((prin * c) - a);
           // document.calc.totpay.value = round((prin * c) - a);
            document.calc.totInt.value = Math.round((prin * c) - a);
            document.calc.totpay.value = Math.round(prin * c);
        }
</script>
<div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="calculators.html">Calculators</a></li>
<li><a href="contactuS.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header><br>
<div class="maincontent">
<div class="content" style="width:100%">
<article class="topcontent">
<header><h2 style="align:center" title="firstpost"><p align="center" style="color: #CF5C3F;">Loan Calculator</p></h2></header>
<footer>
<p class="post-info"></p>
</footer>
<content>
<p>
<center>
    <form name="calc">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Entry</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Principle($)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="loan" id="loan"  placeholder="Enter the amount Required" onkeypress="isNumberKey('loan')"/>
      </td><span id="error"/>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Do you know Rate of Interest</td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" onclick="activate()">Yes<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="No" onclick="deactivate()">No
      </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Interest(%)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" readonly="" placeholder="Enter the Interest Rate" onkeypress="isNumberKey('rate')"  />
      </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tenure(in Months)</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="months" id="months" placeholder="Enter the Tenure in Months" onkeypress="isNumberKey('months')"/>
        </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>EMI</td>
      <td>
        <input name="textfield4" type="text" id="pay"  placeholder="Your EMI" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showpay()"/></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total Interest Paid</td>
      <td>
        <input name="totInt" type="text"  id="totInt" placeholder="Total Interest" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total Repay Amount</td>
      <td>
        <input name="totpay" type="text"  id="totpay" placeholder="Total Amount" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</center>

</p>
</content>
</article>

</div>
</div>


<footer class="mainfooter">
<p>this is copyright &copy;</p>
</footer>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10274/

Answer (score 1):

Try this on angularJS way.

Look this code in angular style. Without Jquery.

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="calculators.html">Calculators</a></li>
<li><a href="contactuS.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header><br>
<div class="maincontent">
<div class="content" style="width:100%">
<article class="topcontent">
<header><h2 style="align:center" title="firstpost"><p align="center" style="color: #CF5C3F;">Loan Calculator</p></h2></header>
<footer>
<p class="post-info"></p>
</footer>
<content ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
<p>
<center>
    <form name="calc">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Entry</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Principle($)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="loan" id="loan" ng-model="loan" placeholder="Enter the amount Required" ng-change="isNumberKey()"/>
      </td><span id="error"/>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Do you know Rate of Interest</td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" ng-change="change()" ng-model="rateint">Yes<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="No" ng-change="change()" ng-model="rateint">No
      </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Interest(%)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" ng-model="rate" placeholder="Enter the Interest Rate" onkeypress="isNumberKey()" ng-disabled="rateint != 'Yes'" />
      </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tenure(in Months)</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="months" id="months" ng-model="months" placeholder="Enter the Tenure in Months"  ng-change="isNumberKey()"/>
        </td><!--<span id="error"/>-->
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>EMI</td>
      <td>
        <input name="textfield4" type="text" id="pay" ng-model="pay" placeholder="Your EMI" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="showpay()"/></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total Interest Paid</td>
      <td>
        <input name="totInt" type="text" ng-model="toInt" id="totInt" placeholder="Total Interest" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total Repay Amount</td>
      <td>
        <input name="totpay" type="text" ng-model="topay" id="totpay" placeholder="Total Amount" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</center>

</p>
</content>
</article>

</div>
</div>


<footer class="mainfooter">
<p>this is copyright &copy;</p>
</footer>
</div>
```

JS

```
function CalcCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.loan = $scope.loan ? $scope.loan : 0
   $scope.rate = $scope.rate ? $scope.rate : 1
   $scope.months = $scope.months ? $scope.months : 1
 $scope.isNumberKey = function() {
            var dd = $scope.loan;
            if (dd && isNaN(dd)) {
                dd = dd.substring(0, (dd.length - 1));
                $scope.loan = dd;
            }
        }



      $scope.change = function(){
          if ($scope.rateint === 'No'){
              var loan = $scope.loan
                if(loan > 50000 && loan < 100000){
               $scope.rate=10;
                }
                if(loan > 100000 && loan < 150000){
              $scope.rate=12;
                }
              }
        }

        $scope.showpay = function() {
            var a = $scope.loan;
            var b = $scope.rate;
            var c = $scope.months
            console.log(a,b,c)
            var n = c ;

            var r = b / (12 * 100);
                                     console.log(b)
            var p = (a * r * Math.pow((1 + r), n)) / (Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1);

            var prin = Math.round(p * 100) / 100;

            $scope.pay = Math.round(prin);
           // document.calc.totInt.value = round((prin * c) - a);
           // document.calc.totpay.value = round((prin * c) - a);
            $scope.toInt = Math.round((prin * c) - a);
            $scope.topay = Math.round(prin * c);
        } 
}
```

See this working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10271/

And after see the angularjs documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api

Comment: Can you please tell how to do this is pure Javascript?

Comment: Please feedback the other answer.